How to make a natural shift from icehouse to greenhouse
Here is the situation. This is the map of a world:

Now, as you'll notice, this world is a icehouse, much like our own. However, it won't stay that way much for longer. Our current icehouse is essentially a fluke- warm equatorial water is blocked from reaching the poles, the northern sea is nearly closed off, and there's land at the south pole. This map has land at the northern pole, but warm equatorial water can reach the north pole, and there's no walled off polar ocean.
So here's the question.  The world will gradually get hotter until all ice on the planet melts. The current temperature is 14 C, and the planet will stop warming at 21 C or so. Assuming it takes 240,000 years to get from 14 to 21 C, what could cause this warming?
Rules: No magic, Pleistocene fauna as a start

pre human? Like what?

For future reference, it is a rule of Stack Exchange that you ask only one question per post. Asking what happens at every step is 3+1=4 questions. Asking more than one specific question at a time is literally a reason to close questions. Also, please be aware that you're asking a very, very broad question. Average climate is (trust me) worthless to you and specific climates in various locations violates that one-question-per-post rule in spades. Climate questions are among the most difficult that we answer and you need to be as focused and specific as humanly possible. (*Continued*)

... Unless all you're looking for is, "the ocean levels will rise and the ice caps will shrink until the warming is done, a few deserts will appear near the equatorial regions." In other words, if you want detailed answers, you need to ask specific questions - one at a time.

this is also a similiar distribution of continetns to when the earth nearly froze solid, you have created 2 isolated polar oceans, there is acutally almost no warm equtorial water in your set up and cold currents are free to circulated completely around the poles isolating them, which just makes them colder. the continets don't disrupt coriolis circulation. your planet is getting colder not hotter, you need a large equtorial ocean, put all the continets together of you want it to warm up.

@JBH understood, will slim it down

"The world will gradually get hotter until all ice on the planet melts": What is driving this massive warming? I do not understand why the world would suddenly flip from having polar ice caps to not having polar ice caps.

@AlexP i was under the impression that this set of continental arrangements would trend towards a hothouse instead of an icehouse like our current set, but john pointed out it's actually trending towards a colder icehouse than our own

@whoamiiamyou: My point is that the premise of the question is that the world right now has ice caps. The question that states that the icecaps will melt and the average temperature will increase by seven degrees centigrade. If the world right now has ice caps, something must happen for them to melt. And something even much stronger has to happen for the temperature to increase by that much.

@AlexP has a good point. You might want to look into Milankovitch cycles.

If you're keen on the arrangement of continents you have there, but want hot - then ask how to achieve that - we excel at solving problems like that.

for warming you want continets running nearly from pole to pole with no gaps so no oceanic current can run around the planet this forces heat distribution towards the poles.  now of course atmosphereic compistion will matter a lot too.

Real-world example provides ready-made technobabble
The funny thing is, something like this has actually happened in relatively recent real-world geological history. It has probably happened many times in more distant geological real-world geological history, but the details of distant geological history are irretrievably lost in the mists of time. But the horrible, terrible, no-good Paleocene–Eocene Thermal Maximum occurred about 55.8 million years ago and lasted, coincidentally, about 200,000 years, almost exactly as requested.
All the quotations in this answer come from the Wikipedia article.

Earth surface temperatures gradually increased by about 6 °C from the late Paleocene through the early Eocene. Superimposed on this long-term, gradual warming were at least three (and probably more) "hyperthermals": geologically brief (less than 200,000 years) events characterized by rapid global warming, major changes in the environment, and massive carbon addition. Though not the first within the Cenozoic, the Paleocene–Eocene Thermal Maximum (PETM) was the most extreme hyperthermal, and stands out as a major change in the lithologic, biotic and geochemical composition of sediment in hundreds of records across Earth.

Oh good. How extreme was this most extreme hyperthermal? Does it satisfy the question's requirement of 7 °C warming? Yes it does:

Estimates of the amount of average global temperature rise at the start of the PETM range from approximately 3 to 6 °C to between 5 and 8 °C.


Proxy data from Esplugafereda in northeastern Spain shows a rapid +8 °C temperature rise, in accordance with existing regional records of marine and terrestrial environments. In Antarctica, at least part of the year saw minimum temperatures of 15 °C.


The average sea surface temperature (SST) reached over 36 °C (97 °F) in the tropics during the PETM, enough to cause heat stress even in organisms resistant to extreme thermal stress, such as dinoflagellates, of which a significant number of species went extinct.T ropical SSTs may have been even higher, exceeding 40 °C. Low latitude Indian Ocean Mg/Ca records show seawater at all depths warmed by ~4-5 °C.

OK, OK, it was bad enough to fulfill the requirements. But the question is, what caused it?

Discriminating between different possible causes of the PETM is difficult. Temperatures were rising globally at a steady pace, and a mechanism must be invoked to produce an instantaneous spike which may have been accentuated or catalyzed by positive feedback or activation of "tipping or points".

Enough with the hedging. We want sweet juicy technobabble for our story. We get it that we don't know for sure what caused it, but what might have caused it? Here is a selection of the competing hypotheses mentioned by the Fount of All Knowledge:

Orbital forcing? Nah, not really.

The orbital forcing hypothesis has been challenged by a study finding the PETM to have coincided with a minimum in the ~400 kyr eccentricity cycle, inconsistent with a proposed orbital trigger for the hyperthermal.


Comet impact? Probably not, but it would make for great visuals.

One theory holds that a 12C-rich comet struck the earth and initiated the warming event. A cometary impact coincident with the P/E boundary can also help explain some enigmatic features associated with this event, such as the iridium anomaly at Zumaia, the abrupt appearance of a localized kaolinitic clay layer with abundant magnetic nanoparticles, and especially the nearly simultaneous onset of the carbon isotope excursion and the thermal maximum.


A key feature and testable prediction of a comet impact is that it should produce virtually instantaneous environmental effects in the atmosphere and surface ocean with later repercussions in the deeper ocean. This would require at least 100 gigatons of extraterrestrial carbon. Such a catastrophic impact should have left its mark on the globe.

(And, of course, the diligent researchers have found several possible marks left by the hypothetical cometary impact. But nothing really spectacular.)

Eruption of large kimberlite field? Yes, yes, yes this is by far the best just-so story! And it has the advantage that it turns out that it all was the fault of Canada!

Although the cause of the initial warming has been attributed to a massive injection of carbon (CO2 and/or CH4) into the atmosphere, the source of the carbon has yet to be found. The emplacement of a large cluster of kimberlite pipes at ~56 Ma in the Lac de Gras region of northern Canada may have provided the carbon that triggered early warming in the form of exsolved magmatic CO2. Calculations indicate that the estimated 900 to 1,100 gigatonnes of carbon required for the initial approximately 3 °C of ocean water warming associated with the Paleocene-Eocene thermal maximum could have been released during the emplacement of a large kimberlite cluster. The transfer of warm surface ocean water to intermediate depths led to thermal dissociation of seafloor methane hydrates, providing the isotopically depleted carbon that produced the carbon isotopic excursion. The coeval ages of two other kimberlite clusters in the Lac de Gras field and two other early Cenozoic hyperthermals indicate that CO2 degassing during kimberlite emplacement is a plausible source of the CO2 responsible for these sudden global warming events.


Volcanic activity? Volcanoes are big, they are fiery, they make for great visuals, and they can always take the blame when something bad happens. Volcanoes are bad by nature; that's what they are.

One of the leading candidates for the cause of the observed carbon cycle disturbances and global warming is volcanic activity associated with the North Atlantic Igneous Province, which is believed to have released more than 10,000 gigatons of carbon during the PETM based on the relatively isotopically heavy values of the initial carbon addition.


Intrusions of hot magma into carbon-rich sediments may have triggered the degassing of isotopically light methane in sufficient volumes to cause global warming and the observed isotope anomaly.


Methane clathrate release. Possible, it is always possible. It is possible even right now, as the dear readers are reading this answer: one of the great fears of climatologists worldwide is what would happen if the methane trapped in the cold traps begins to escape its icy prisons.

Methane hydrate dissolution has been invoked as a highly plausible causal mechanism for the carbon isotope excursion and warming observed at the PETM. The most obvious feedback mechanism that could amplify the initial perturbation is that of methane clathrates. Under certain temperature and pressure conditions, methane, which is being produced continually by decomposing microbes in sea bottom sediments, is stable in a complex with water, which forms ice-like cages trapping the methane in solid form. As temperature rises, the pressure required to keep this clathrate configuration stable increases, so shallow clathrates dissociate, releasing methane gas to make its way into the atmosphere. Methane is a potent greenhouse gas as it is released into the atmosphere, so it causes warming, and as the ocean transports this warmth to the bottom sediments, it destabilizes more clathrates.




Add the Siletzia & Yakutat vulcanism and you have multiple large volcanic activities in the same age.
